# how export variable in ES6 in Chrome/Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, ecmascript-6

In latest versions of Firefox and Chrome, I try make export variable.

index.js:

```
'use strict'
import { bla } from './helper';
console.log(bla);
```

helper.js:

```
export var bla = 20;
```

but Chrome console display follow error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word

firefox console display follow error message:
SyntaxError: modules are not implemented yet

> import { bla } from './helper'; <--

also I try follow variant index.js:

```
'use strict'
import { bla } from './helper.js';
console.log(bla);
```

also I try follow variant index.js:

```
'use strict'
import { bla } from 'helper.js';
console.log(bla);
```

but the error message remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported in Firefox and Chrome. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Browser_compatibility.

You'll need some kind of preprocessor or transpiler to make this work.