# import / export in ES6 Transpilers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, transpiler

> This is not a duplicate of below questions which is dealing with browser specific questions. I'm expecting an answer whether `import / export` will work in Client side or not.

1. [ECMA 6 Not working although experimental js is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32809728/ecma-6-not-working-although-experimental-js-is-enabled)
2. [how export variable in ES6 in Chrome/Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541728/how-export-variable-in-es6-in-chrome-firefox)

```js
//lib.js

export const sqrt = Math.sqrt;
export function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}
export function diag(x, y) {
    return sqrt(square(x) + square(y));
}
  
//main.js
  
"use strict";

import { square, diag } from 'lib';
console.log(square(11)); // 121
console.log(diag(4, 3)); // 5
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Import Check</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Error that I'm getting in Chrome:
>   [image]
>
> Tested Browser: Google Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106

1. Is that possible to make the code working in any browser or not ?
2. Lets say, we have chosen one transpiler (`BabelJS`) and code got transpiled. Will the `import` / `export` file code snippet will work in the Client side or Server side (In node Server as require method)?

Comment: Why is your title "import/export in ES6 transpilers" when your question is about chrome?

Comment: edit your question if you think that it is not duplicate.

Comment: @torazaburo, i have updated the question what actually i expect !

Comment: Earlier marked original and current questions are same. its need to reopened !

Comment: @torazaburo, please revisit the question to reopen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) says

> Note: This feature is not implemented in any browsers natively at this time. It is implemented in many transpilers, such as the Traceur Compiler, Babel or Rollup.

For example after using babel on your code snippet you will get something like this:

```js
//lib.js

"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});
exports.square = square;
exports.diag = diag;
var sqrt = Math.sqrt;
exports.sqrt = sqrt;

function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}

function diag(x, y) {
    return sqrt(square(x) + square(y));
}
//------ main.js ------
'use strict';

var _lib = require('lib');

console.log((0, _lib.square)(11)); // 121
console.log((0, _lib.diag)(4, 3)); // 5
```

This code is enough to use in NodeJs.
But to use in browser you need something like require.js or browserify.
In this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hTLhAJNRFBzlPx2oBD4B?p=preview) I used [require1k](http://stuk.github.io/require1k/)

Comment: you meant to say its not possible to test without transpilers like babel, traceur, typescript even we add use strict

Comment: `"use strict";`  Defines that JavaScript code should be executed in "strict mode".

Comment: i expect the answer as working code snippet to get the import feature to work not only reference!

Comment: @Venkatraman I used babel and got code that I added to answer.

Comment: @Venkatraman also look at this questions [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it?rq=1) [second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34551070/use-babel-with-javascript)

Comment: it says Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Comment: explained how to use in browser. Added plunker

Comment: Nice. will proceed further once its get reopened.

Answer (score 0):

Like Manasov Daniel said

> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) says
>
> > Note: This feature is not implemented in any browsers natively at this time. It is implemented in many transpilers, such as the Traceur Compiler, Babel or Rollup.

With newer versions of ECMAScript (before implementation in browsers), you usually have to transpile (compile) the ECMAScript code into JavaScript. The tool of my choice is **Babel**, although there are many others out there.

You can install Babel CLI by going to your terminal and entering:

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel-cli
```

Everytime you make a change to your ES, you should recompile to JS.

Comment: what babelJS exactly does if we give import statement one line. will that convert it to require ?

Comment: Yes it does. ES6 transiplers will always convert ES6 to its latest version of JavaScript counterparts

Comment: what are those, share it for better understanding